# Unable to enable / configure Bluetooth for Lenovo Y520

Tags: linux, bluetooth, kernel, kernel-module, linux-device-driver

I have [Lenovo Y520 (Legion)](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ua/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y520-15ikbn/80wk/80wk00v5ra/pf0uvxby) with Gentoo and failed to setup Bluetooth support. As [documentation says](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/legion_y520-15ikbn_hmm_201701.pdf):

> Bluetooth wireless * Combo w/ Wifi card

I followed the instruction from https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Bluetooth but still no luck.

**Linux Kernel:** 5.7.8-gentoo

**Kernel Config:**

```
$ cat /usr/src/linux/.config | egrep -i "usb|blue" | grep -v '^#'

CONFIG_USB_NET_DRIVERS=y
CONFIG_MOUSE_SYNAPTICS_USB=m
CONFIG_MEDIA_USB_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_USB_VIDEO_CLASS=m
CONFIG_USB_VIDEO_CLASS_INPUT_EVDEV=y
CONFIG_USB_GSPCA=m
CONFIG_SND_USB=y
CONFIG_USB_HID=y
CONFIG_USB_HIDDEV=y
CONFIG_USB_OHCI_LITTLE_ENDIAN=y
CONFIG_USB_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_USB_COMMON=y
CONFIG_USB_ARCH_HAS_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB=y
CONFIG_USB_PCI=y
CONFIG_USB_ANNOUNCE_NEW_DEVICES=y
CONFIG_USB_DEFAULT_PERSIST=y
CONFIG_USB_AUTOSUSPEND_DELAY=2
CONFIG_USB_MON=y
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_PCI=y
CONFIG_USB_XHCI_PLATFORM=m
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_TT_NEWSCHED=y
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_PCI=y
CONFIG_USB_OHCI_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_OHCI_HCD_PCI=y
CONFIG_USB_UHCI_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_PRINTER=y
CONFIG_USB_WDM=m
CONFIG_USB_STORAGE=y
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL=m
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_SIMPLE=m
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_PL2303=m
CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK_USB=y
```

**Loaded modules:**

```
$ lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    24576  1 wmi_bmof
xhci_plat_hcd          16384  0
cdc_wdm                20480  0
pl2303                 24576  0
usb_serial_simple      20480  0
usbserial              40960  2 pl2303,usb_serial_simple
snd_hda_codec_realtek   106496  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          36864  6
snd_intel_dspcfg       16384  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         118784  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_hda_core           77824  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_pcm               102400  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
iwlmvm                348160  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      28672  1 intel_rapl_msr
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
intel_pch_thermal      16384  0
iwlwifi               327680  1 iwlmvm
configs                45056  0
psmouse               151552  0
rmi_smbus              16384  0
rmi_i2c                16384  0
rmi_core               77824  2 rmi_smbus,rmi_i2c
elan_i2c               40960  0
synaptics_usb          16384  0
synaptics_i2c          16384  0
ntfs                  212992  0
ecb                    16384  0
cpufreq_userspace      16384  0
v4l2_dv_timings        36864  0
gspca_main             28672  0
uvcvideo              106496  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  2 gspca_main,uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  2 gspca_main,uvcvideo
videodev              212992  3 gspca_main,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       49152  3 gspca_main,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
i2c_mux                16384  0
bluetooth             462848  6
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
ecc                    32768  1 ecdh_generic
efivarfs               16384  1
fuse                  122880  1
```

**USB:**

```
$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b57e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd EasyCamera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 

$ lsusb -t

/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=, 12M
```

Relevant part from `lsusb -v`:

```
$ lsusb -v -d 8087:0a2b

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          224 Wireless
  bDeviceSubClass         1 Radio Frequency
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Bluetooth
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x8087 Intel Corp.
  idProduct          0x0a2b 
  bcdDevice            0.10
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x00b1
    bNumInterfaces          2
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0000  1x 0 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0000  1x 0 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       1
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0009  1x 9 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0009  1x 9 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       2
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0011  1x 17 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0011  1x 17 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       3
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0019  1x 25 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0019  1x 25 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       4
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0021  1x 33 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0021  1x 33 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       5
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       224 Wireless
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Radio Frequency
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0031  1x 49 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0031  1x 49 bytes
        bInterval               1
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

**PCI:**

```
$ lspci -kk

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 630
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo CM238 HD Audio Controller
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
02:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo SD/MMC Card Reader Controller
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM961/PM961
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
```

**Kernel Logs:**

```
$ dmesg | egrep -i "usb|blue"

[    0.164569] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.164569] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.164569] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.164569] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.519213] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.519222] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.519231] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.519359] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.520678] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.07
[    0.520680] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.520682] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.520684] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.7.8-gentoo xhci-hcd
[    0.520685] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    0.520788] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.521259] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.521263] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    0.521286] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.07
[    0.521288] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.521290] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.521291] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.7.8-gentoo xhci-hcd
[    0.521293] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    0.521351] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.521448] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[    0.521576] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
[    0.521585] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    0.575596] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    0.575597] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    0.846512] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    0.975882] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b, bcdDevice=12.09
[    0.975883] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    0.975884] usb 1-3: Product: USB Receiver
[    0.975884] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    0.977856] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:046D:C52B.0001/input/input6
[    1.029722] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52B.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
[    1.031485] input: Logitech USB Receiver Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:046D:C52B.0002/input/input7
[    1.031548] input: Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:046D:C52B.0002/input/input8
[    1.083687] input: Logitech USB Receiver System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/0003:046D:C52B.0002/input/input9
[    1.084062] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52B.0002: input,hiddev96,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input1
[    1.086107] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev97,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input2
[    1.198533] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.276317] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    1.276325] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    1.276328] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    1.276329] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    1.276331] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    1.276922] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    1.276922] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    1.276924] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    1.285649] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    1.285650] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    1.290789] usbcore: registered new interface driver synaptics_usb
[    1.328502] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb_serial_simple
[    1.328511] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for carelink
[    1.328516] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for zio
[    1.328520] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for funsoft
[    1.328525] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for flashloader
[    1.328529] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for google
[    1.328534] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for libtransistor
[    1.328538] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for vivopay
[    1.328543] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for moto_modem
[    1.328547] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for motorola_tetra
[    1.328552] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for novatel_gps
[    1.328556] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for hp4x
[    1.328560] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for suunto
[    1.328566] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for siemens_mpi
[    1.329088] usbcore: registered new interface driver pl2303
[    1.329094] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for pl2303
[    1.329795] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_wdm
[    1.384686] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b57e, bcdDevice=87.40
[    1.384687] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    1.384688] usb 1-6: Product: EasyCamera
[    1.384689] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd.
[    1.384689] usb 1-6: SerialNumber: 0001
[    1.400789] input: EasyCamera: EasyCamera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input15
[    1.514536] usb 1-11: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    1.641309] usb 1-11: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0a2b, bcdDevice= 0.10
[    1.641311] usb 1-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

**Daemon logs:**

```
$ journalctl -b0 -u bluetooth

-- Logs begin at Mon 2020-07-13 19:33:32 EEST, end at Thu 2020-07-16 18:16:15 EEST. --
Jul 16 18:16:04 saturn systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jul 16 18:16:04 saturn bluetoothd[7173]: Bluetooth daemon 5.54
Jul 16 18:16:04 saturn systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jul 16 18:16:04 saturn bluetoothd[7173]: Starting SDP server
Jul 16 18:16:04 saturn bluetoothd[7173]: Bluetooth management interface 1.16 initialized
```

**rfkill:**

```
$ rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

Note, `bluetoothctl` shows nothing:

```
$ bluetoothctl

Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]#
```

Relevant part of `lshw`:

```
*-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 05
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:120
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: HD Graphics 630
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:125 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:129 memory:a1400000-a140ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.7.8-gentoo xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.07
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=16 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: USB Receiver
                   vendor: Logitech
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@1:3
                   version: 12.09
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Video
                   product: EasyCamera
                   vendor: Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd.
                   physical id: 6
                   bus info: usb@1:6
                   version: 87.40
                   serial: 0001
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:2 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: b
                   bus info: usb@1:b
                   version: 0.10
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

Please note:

> *-usb:2 UNCLAIMED

Any suggestions as to where to go next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

Required kernel modules were missing:

```
bnep
btintel
hci_uart
```

As well as kernel configuration:

```
CONFIG_BT_BCM=m
CONFIG_BT_RTL=m
CONFIG_BT_HCIBTUSB=m
CONFIG_BT_HCIBTUSB_BCM=y
CONFIG_BT_HCIBTUSB_RTL=y
```

Below are the steps I took.

Get Product ID

```
$ lsusb -v -d 8087:0a2b 2>/dev/null | grep idProduct | awk '{print $2}'
0x0a2b
```

Find kernel configuration

```
$ grep -R 0x0a2b /usr/src/linux/ | grep driver_info | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'
 BTUSB_INTEL_NEW |
```

Open kernel configuration (`make menuconfig`), search for `BTUSB` keyword, and enable a suitable module, keeping in mind the vendor description:

[image]